# How do I grab a really simple element using XML?

Tags: ruby, rexml

I'm struggling to figure out XPath and REXML, every single thing I try, even copied from books, returns nil. And I'm trying to do the simplest possible output of data... my file looks like

```
<profile>
    <userid>3002</userid>
</profile>
```

I want to get `3002` out. What on Earth do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you post a code.
Well, just to show you a direction, try this:

```
require 'rexml/document'

xml = '<profile>
         <userid>3002</userid>
       </profile>'

doc = REXML::Document.new xml
item = REXML::XPath.first(doc, '//profile/userid').text
p item
#=> 3002
```

It finds first `userid` element inside `profile` and takes it's text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use excellent [`Nokogiri`](http://nokogiri.org/) Gem too. Here is how I'd code this -

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = '<profile>
         <userid>3002</userid>
      </profile>'

doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse xml
p doc.at('userid').text
# => "3002"
```